# Quickly access any app on an iPhone iOS5 using home or volume buttons?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios

Is there a way to quickly access apps by holding down the home button, volume button or double tapping any of the buttons while in lock screen.

I believe there was a way to do it with a Jailbroken iPhone but I am looking to do it with iOS 5.

Any suggestions? 
Or will I just have to wait for an iOS 5 jailbreak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double tap the home button → It works great.

Comment: that just gives me a screen for music player and a camera icon. Is it possible to make double taping the home button or any other combination access a different app like the voice memo app so I can quickly record some audio?

Comment: Did you try and swipe left/right when that popped up? All my apps are accessible using it.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the multitasking feature while you are using the iphone and its currently unlocked, correct me if im wrong. I need a way to access those apps while the screen is locked. There are a few apps I use more than others and I would like to use them while driving and I can't really look at the screen. Often times I just want to record a quick note. That is why I want to push a button then record a quick voice note. Any ideas?

Comment: I get what you're saying; unfortunately as you already know the 'stock' options are quite limited. If your iphone is brand new I wouldn't even consider jb unless it was out of warranty. 

One thing I thought of though, specific to you wanting to record a quick note; why not just set the camera to video mode and from there you've basically got your voice recorder with two taps directly from the lock screen. You could always eliminate the video track later; it's certainly an option.

Comment: Well, that looks like the best option right now. I don't know if its that much quicker though... my video seems to take quite awhile to load. :) Thanks for your help. Hopefully we get an untethered jailbreak for iOS 5 soon.